# Compile the sources using Clang API in ios app?

Tags: ios, api, compiler-construction, clang

Since on iOS it's restricted to launch external processes (compiler in this case) is it possible to compile c/c++ sources with clang via API as shared lib to walk-around the restriction? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

No. Basically you can not run code that Apple can not validate the operation of.

This is for a couple of reasons (IMO):
 1. Security against rouge code not in the app at review time.
 2. Parental permissions: Apple provides parents the ability to restrict what content is available on an age basis, if they can not see the content they can not review the content and assertion if it has an applicable age rating.

Comment: Can't understand your (Apple's) arguments. Does it mean that any IDE with compiler integrated will be rejected for sure? Does the fact that target platform differs from host system change anything (compiled code will not work on ios)?

Comment: Is what you describe in the last sentence what you want to do? Possibly. Better yet, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'd like to port IDE with integrated cross-compiler

Comment: Xcode, the IDS, is closed source, runs on OSX only so that is out, you would have to go with something like Eclipse. The compiler is Clang, the debugger is LLDB and they are open source. The goal is very ambitious, how man-years do you have? Take a look at [Coderunner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coderunner/id433335799‎) for an example that is in the direction you are looking.

Comment: I have all the necessary knowledge, 15+ y experience and ready similar project on Android so the question is Apple limitations only

Comment: Look at the history of [Briefs](http://giveabrief.com), the first version was not allowed by Apple, the current version is. Contact an Apple evangelist, their contact info is usually at the end of the WWDC presentation videos and get to know them. While you probably will not get a green light you may get a red light, I have several times. Yet they were willing to explore work-arounds and give hints of what they thought.